# Output formate for calendar in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, printing, calendar, format

I would like to format the output in terms of calendar format. I have tried with print statement, but could not achieve as I expected because rows and column is not aligned properly.Could anyone help me to format and align the output? Here I have shared my entire code which is written in Python 3.6. the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51354543/how-to-print-calendar-in-monthwise-matrix-format-in-python-3-6) I have asked before but could not get any reply. but this code is little better than my previous code.

```
import calendar
import datetime     
tamil_day = ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thusday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday')
tamil_month = ('Chithirai','Vaikasi','Aani','Aadi','Aavani','Puratasi','Ipasi','Karthikai','Maargali','Thai','Masi','Panguni')
'''SAKA year Each month starting day in AD year 1st position for common year and 0th position for leap year'''

saka_month_starting_day_in_ad = (21,22,21,22,22,23,23,23,23,22,22,21,20)

'''equal month in AD year for SAKA month starting'''
ad_month = (3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2)

''' number of days in each month in SAKA year. add one ine more day each month for calculation'''
no_days_in_saka_month = (31,30,31,31,31,31,31,30,30,30,30,30,30)

def saka_month(saka_year,month):
    ad_year = saka_year+78
    saka_month = []
    temp = 0
    if month == 1 and calendar.isleap(ad_year):
        first_day = datetime.date(ad_year,ad_month[month],saka_month_starting_day_in_ad[month-1]).weekday()
    else:
        first_day = datetime.date(ad_year,ad_month[month],saka_month_starting_day_in_ad[month]).weekday()
    while first_day != temp:
        saka_month.append(str('  '))
        temp+=1
    for day in range(1,(no_days_in_saka_month[month]+1)):
        saka_month.append(str(day))
        if day == no_days_in_saka_month[month] and calendar.isleap(ad_year):
            saka_month.append(str(day+1))
    for i in range(0,42,7):
         print(*saka_month[i:i+7],sep='           ',end='\n')
         print('\n')

def saka_year_print(saka_year):
    for month in range(0,12):
        print('{:*^80}'.format(tamil_month[month]))
        print('\n')
        print(*tamil_day,sep='     ')
        print('\n','\n','\n')
        saka_month(saka_year,month)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution to my problem. just add str.center() for every list element. in my code at line no.47,50 and 52 you can add the center() function so that we can get aligned matrix kind of calendar in month view.
thank you